# What does text.inject("", :<<) do in Ruby when working with codepoints?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to build a cipher for The Odin Project Ruby course, and I needed to put all the letters from an array of letters I created back into one big string with all of them in it

```
text.inject("", :<<)
```

it seemed to do the trick.  I was wondering if anyone could explain the inject method and how it works to put the letters back together again in one big string.

The array I was working with was

```
["W", "h", "a", "t", " ", "a", " ", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", "!"]
```

Comment: Did you try to read documentation?

Comment: @llya yeah, I understand what the quotes do, but I wasn't really sure how the :<< maps thru each letter and puts in in one big string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"foo" << "bar"` joins the strings `"foo"` and `"bar"` into `"foobar"`.

```
["W", "h", "a", "t", " ", "a", " ", "s", "t", "r", "i", "n", "g", "!"].inject(:<<)
```

inserts the `<<` between element of the Array (i.e., each string in it) and is equivalent to

```
"W" << "h" << "a" << "t" << " " << "a" << " " << "s" << "t" << "r" << "i" << "n" << "g" << "!"
```

`:<<` is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html) that is the name of the method `<<` of String.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the difference between :<< and <<

Comment: @AdamG `:<<` just a symbol representation of `<<` method.

Comment: `:<<` is a symbol that represents `<<` and some methods take this as an argument and use it as a hit as to which method to call on things. `inject`/`reduce` are like that. A series of things like `"".send(:<<, "W")` is what happens internally.